# Bitbucket pipeline docker volume permissions at recreating containers

Tags: django, docker, pipeline, docker-volume, bitbucket-pipelines

I have deployed django app with docker container. Source code of the app is on the Bitbucket repository. Now I want to setup pipeline for `master` branch which is intended to make deployment automatic on merge. Problematic part of the pipeline script is below:

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

Above line resuts with error that says:

```
Permission denied: '/path/to/docker/volume/pgdb'
```

My docker-compose file section related to postgres is below:

```
  postgres:
    container_name:  arw-postgres
    image:           postgres:11
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./pgdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file: .env
```

The above specified `docker-compose` command runs normally with `sudo` privilege. Actually, I can connect to remote host with root user and can run this command. But I don't want to expose my root user's credentials. How can I recreate my docker container without `sudo` privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was non-existence of `.dockerignore` file. I simply added `.dockerignore` file with the content `pgdb` at the same level with `Dockerfile`. This file avoids copying of protected `pgdb` folder to docker container, so no permission error occurs.